# QuerySelector vs .target

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code, how comes the const password uses .querySelector in the authorize() function? I am a bit confused because:

1. JSX isn't strictly Javascript, so how come you can even use .querySelector?
2. And secondly, in JavaScript, you'd just select input as this would represent the password input box, but in this case input[type="password"] has been selected. Is this because in HTML the input boxes are not named so you have to differentiate them?
3. If authorize() uses e.target, why is querySelector needed? won't authorize already realize the password input field is what is triggering the function? Or am I wrong and instead, the 'e' triggering authorize() is the form and so similar to document.querySelector, you then need to select the input field itself as this is a subtype of the form?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      password: 'swordfish',
      authorized: false
    };
    this.authorize = this.authorize.bind(this);
  }

  authorize(e) {
    const password = **e.target.querySelector(
      'input[type="password"]').value;**
    const auth = (password == this.state.password);
    this.setState({
      authorized: auth
    });
  }

  render() {
    let login = (
      **<form action="#" onSubmit={this.authorize}>**
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
    );

    let contactInfo = (
      <ul>
          <li>
            client@example.com
          </li>
          <li>
            555.555.5555
          </li>
        </ul>
    );

    return (
      <div id="authorization">
        <h1>{this.state.authorized ? 'Contact' : 'Enter the Password'}</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.authorized ? contactInfo : login}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Contact />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);

Thanks!
```

Comment: JSX compiles to Javascript, it's not a replacement for the DOM. I assume the code acesses the DOM directly because the author isn't very good at React.

Comment: @GuyIncognito what do you mean by this statement? "Replacement for the DOM"? How else would you access and change the DOM?

Comment: You asked "JSX isn't strictly Javascript, so how come you can even use .querySelector?" which doesn't make any sense, the browser always uses DOM so you can always use .querySelector. JSX doesn't replace the DOM in any way.

Comment: got it thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2):

JSX is extended syntax for JS. Adding more stuff doesn’t stop you using existing stuff.

There is no *need* to use a selector that specific in that piece of code. It does not harm and can aid readability.

The target of the submit event is the form, not the input. If you need to read the input, then you have to select it *somehow*. `querySelector` is a pretty common approach.

---

That said, this is not an idiomatic approach to writing React applications. See [the documentation on forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for the accepted React approach.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to have controlled components in React and keep the input value inside state and let React be the single source of truth, not leave it to the DOM to decide what's what. A simple example, using hooks, would be:

```
import React from 'react';

const SimpleExample = () => {
  // use a piece of state to track and hold the input value
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

  // change state on input change
  const handleChange = event => setInputVal(event.target.value);

  // react also handles submit 
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    // prevent default browser behaviour
    event.preventDefault();
    // you can send values held inside state to the back-end here
    console.log("Submitting...", inputVal)
  }

  return (
   <form onSubmit={event => handleSubmit(event)}>
     <input 
       type="password" 
       // the value of the input is held by React state
       value={inputVal} 
       // change state something is being typed inside input
       onChange={event => handleChange(event)} 
     />
     <button>Submit</button>
   </form>
  )
}
```